# SOCK_DGRAM support for unamed on Twisted

Tags: python, network-programming, twisted

I want a program to connect with my python program, using twisted. I've succeded to start the connection using 'SOCK_STREAM' with a named pipe (using the twisted class 'UNIXServerEndpoint'). But the next step requires to listen for an unamed pipe using 'SOCK_DGRAM'. It seems support is not implemented in Twisted (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5574). How can I set the socket for listening "manually" and connect it to Twisted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of "named pipes" isn't quite accurate.  A UNIX socket is not a named pipe.

However, assuming that you mean an `AF_UNIX`/`SOCK_DGRAM` socket, the way to do this is `reactor.`[`listenUNIXDatagram`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorUNIXDatagram.html#listenUNIXDatagram)(...)

Comment: It seems implemented as you described but cannot be used directly as UNIXDatagramClient and UNIXDatagramServer are not available. I'm working on it...

Comment: Endpoints are for SOCK_STREAM servers and clients.  listenUNIXDatagram should satisfy your requirements if you need SOCK_DGRAM.